# Java Swing repaint(), revalidate() issue after addind Jpanel to Jpanel

Tags: java, swing

i'm quite new in java and i'm trying create my own scrabble game. I created my own classes Board and Tile both JPanels. while im drawing tiles on my Board :

```
Tile tile = new Tile(currentlyChosenLetter, jump);
board.add(tile);
tile.setBounds(x * jump + 1, y * jump + 1, jump - 2, jump - 2);
```

when im doing like this everything seems working fine :

[image: Without repaint]

but after adding :

```
board.revalidate();
board.repaint();
```

tiles are misplaced, i need to repaint in case of removing Tiles.

[image: WithRepaint]

x and y im getting from my mouse position :

```
int jump = board.getHeight() / 15;
int x = (e.getX() / jump);
int y = (e.getY() / jump);
```

where e is MouseEvent.

Comment: 1) *"..have 2 problems"* Then start two question threads. SO is a Q&A Site, not a help desk. 2) Post a [mcve] (for each question thread, with only the code related to that problem). 3) Don't forget to ask an explicit question - **Q** & A site.

Answer (score 1):

```
board.revalidate();
board.repaint();
```

The revalidate() statement invokes the layout manager so the child components are given a size and location based on the rules of the layout manager. The default layout manager for a `JPanel` is the `FlowLayout` so the components appear on a single line.

So **don't** use `setBounds(...)`. Instead use a proper layout manager like the `GridLayout` and add components to each square of the grid.

I would suggestion you might want to a `JLabel` to each grid. Then you can add and `Icon` to each label with the default icon for a given square. Then as a letter is added you replace the Icon with the text.

Comment: @MaciekTrystuła, you seemed to miss the point of the entire answer. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers, not a null layout. There is no need to use a null layout. This is a perfect scenario for using a GridLayout. It does all the layout management code for you. Don't reinvent the wheel!!!